# Where are the PySpark docs' DataFrames df, df2, df3 etc. defined?

Tags: pyspark

In the PySpark docs, I see many examples working on sample DataFrames like `df4` [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.GroupedData.pivot).

Where are they defined? I'd like to see them in full to better understand the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are defined in **`_test()`** method in [**`Class GroupedData(...)`**](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/sql/group.html)

[image]

```
from pyspark.sql import Row

df4 = sc.parallelize([Row(course="dotNET", year=2012, earnings=10000),
                                   Row(course="Java",   year=2012, earnings=20000),
                                   Row(course="dotNET", year=2012, earnings=5000),
                                   Row(course="dotNET", year=2013, earnings=48000),
                                   Row(course="Java",   year=2013, earnings=30000)]).toDF()
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a quick way to get one of them, e.g. df4, into my local session to be able to work with it? Or do I just have to copy the code out of this function?

Comment: Oh, also, the df4 defined here has the columns 'name', 'age', and 'height', but in the .pivot() documentation I've linked in my question, the data frame seems to be a different one.

Comment: @AlexanderEngelhardt, pivot is part of **GroupedData** class added link and createdataframe to the answer!

Comment: Thanks for the edit! That's the one I was looking for :)